# Python HttpRequest receiving multiple arguments in one header

Tags: python, http-headers, azure-functions, httprequest

How do I manage an API url like this:

```
http://localhost:7071/api?type=cat,dog,bird
```

Rather than,

```
http://localhost:7071/api?type=cat&type=dog&type=bird
```

My current code:

```
def main( req : func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Blahblah')

    feed_type = req.params.get('type')

    if not type:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            type = req_body.get('type')

    #Then, maybe iterate over as list?


if feed_type :

feed_type.split(',') # split to list #[cat,dog,bird]

if (feed_type is not None) & ('cat' in feed_type) & ('dog' not in feed_type) & ('bird' not in feed_type):
    return func.HttpResponse(result, mimetype='application/json')

elif (feed_type is not None) & ('dog' in feed_type) & ('cat' not in feed_type) & ('bird' not in feed_type):
    return func.HttpResponse(result, mimetype='application/json')

elif (feed_type is not None) & ('bird' in feed_type) & ('cat' not in feed_type) & ('dog' not in feed_type):
    return func.HttpResponse(result, mimetype='application/json')

elif (feed_type is not None) & ('cat' in feed_type) & ('dog' in feed_type) & ('bird' not in feed_type):
    return func.HttpResponse(result, mimetype='application/json')

elif (feed_type is not None) & ('cat' in feed_type) & ('bird' in feed_type) & ('dog' not in feed_type):
    return func.HttpResponse(result, mimetype='application/json')

elif (feed_type is not None) & ('dog' in feed_type) & ('bird' in feed_type) & ('cat' not in feed_type):
    return func.HttpResponse(result, mimetype='application/json')

elif (feed_type is not None) & ('cat' in feed_type) & ('dog' in feed_type) & ('bird' in feed_type):
    return func.HttpResponse(result, mimetype='application/json')
```

See here I need to do all possible permutation. However, this case, it is fixed between `cat/dog/bird`. Is there any efficient way to handle this in python?

Comment: not `,` but `&` - `type=cat&type=dog&type=bird`. Some frameworks can get it as list of data but it is not standard. Frankly I would keep `type=cat,dog,bird`

Comment: oh yes, my own mistake. ill change that! @furas

Comment: In this case since you want to keep `type=cat,dog,bird`, how do you handle it? @furas

Comment: @furas updated my answer

Comment: I would simply use `split(',')` to convert it to list. There is no need to use any special for this.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do - in all situations you returns the same `result`

Comment: BTW: you should use `and` instead of `&` which is for bit-wise operatins - `111 & 010 gives 010`

Comment: frankly, your problem has nothing to do with method which you used to send data `type=cat,dog,bird` or `type=cat&type=dog&type=bird` - in both situations you may get list with all values and all problem is later.

Comment: you could nest `if` to make it more readable - `if feed_type: ... other-shorter-if-else...` You could also use `len(feed_type)` to make it more readable - ``if feed_type: if len(feed_type) ==1: ... other-shorter-if-else...  if len(feed_type) == 2: ... other-shorter-if-else... ` but all depend what you want to send as result. Maybe there is no need to make all this tests if you return always the same data.